# openpyxl treats numeric values as dates. Result: OverflowError: date value out of range

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlwt

I'm migrating Excel export routines from `xlwt` to `openpyxl`. Everything is honky-dory, until I want to actually save what I cooked up. A garbage collection kicks in under the hood of `openpyxl` and it throws an error, since numbers like 5 or 6 (measurements), or 24242757 (id) are seemingly considered as date. With `xlwt` we didn't have any code in place to suggest to the library that these values are numbers and not dates. (I worked on Excel exporting on multiple platforms before and I know that deep inside Excel dates are actually integers (`OADate`)).

```
OverflowError : date value out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\foobar\spoolerque\models.py", line 82, in run
result = task_function(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\ratings\views.py", line 1332, in create_analytics_report_task
    return foobar_export(task=task, players=report_list, ev=ev, sort_by=sb)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\ratings\views.py", line 1177, in foobar_export
    xls_export.save(file_contents)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\main\utils.py", line 602, in save
    self.wb.save(io)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook.py", line 214, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 150, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 133, in save
    self.write_data(archive)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 64, in write_data
    shared_string_table = self._write_string_table(archive)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 84, in _write_string_table
    ws.garbage_collect()
  File "C:\Users\foobar\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet.py", line 478, in garbage_collect
    iteritems(self._cells) if (not cell.merged and cell.value in ('', None) and \
  File "C:\Users\foobar\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell.py", line 319, in _get_value
    value = self._shared_date.from_julian(value)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\env\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\shared\date_time.py", line 162, in from_julian
    return EPOCH + datetime.timedelta(days=utc_days)
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

Did anyone run into this? I don't see obvious reports about that, so I guess I'm doing something wrong?

---

Update 1

Turns out the version of openpyxl in the project was *extremely old* (1.6.1). Old enough that the API changed enough (style for example) that I need to work on that. I expect the new version (2.3.5) to be smooth.

---

Update 2

Successfully exported xlsx.

Comment: (Garbage collection in an excel lib? Why???)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using an old version of openpyxl. The garbage collection was there to free up memory be removing empty cells but hasn't been used for several versions.

Excel differentiates between dates and numbers solely through the use of the formatting. openpyxl also relies on this information when reading files or uses it when converting from Python to Excel otherwise numbers are numbers. However, some of the older versions also included type inference by default where some strings would be checked to see if they resembled particularly formatted numbers think of something like '2016-05-05'. Again, this hasn't been the case for a while.

I suggest that you upgrade openpyxl and, should the problems persist, file a bug report with sample code and file.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, I see we are using version 1.6.1, a "little bit" behind (3+ years).